# Не получается добавить сочетание горячих клавиш в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, kali-linux, hotkeys

Не могу назначить `"cursorLeft"` сочетанию клавиш  `"alt+h"` .
Вот мои настройки  keybindings.json

```
[    { "key": "alt+h",                  "command": "cursorLeft",
        "when": "textInputFocus" },
    { "key": "alt+l",                  "command": "cursorRight",
        "when": "textInputFocus" },
    { "key": "alt+k",                  "command": "cursorUp",
        "when": "textInputFocus" },
    { "key": "alt+j",                  "command": "cursorDown",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    }]
```

При этом остальные сочетания работают нормально. Если назначить другое сочетание клавиш, то тогда работает, только <alt+h> не работает. У меня стоит Линукс.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение. Если заменить `"alt+h"` на
"alt+H", это будет работать. Результат всё равно получается не очень. Комбинации стрелок с альтом иногда подвисают, или работают не совсем так как от них ожидаешь.